# Скользящие заголовки как?

Tags: android

[image: Пример]

Приветствую! 
Помогите пожалуйста, хочу написать вот такой скользящий заголовок, но не знаю куда копать, в интернете перерыл инфу о sticky headers, но мне показалось что это не совсем то. 
В примере как бы получается что лейбл с буквой всегда в списке и меняется только его top значение. Но не знаю как такое реализовать.

Comment: А эта буква стоит на месте и меняется, когда её пересекает элемент, начинающийся на другую букву, или она уезжает за последним и выезжает другая?

Comment: @woesss Обнофил гифку, надеюсь это поможет ответить на ваш вопрос.